# Jquery Input fields within Class Visible or Not

Tags: jquery

Before I start, I'm a new to jquery, but I'm loving everything I've learned.

I have a large form that has several hidden divs which become visible only if a specific input has a value or a specific checkbox is checked. Each div has a class called "start-hidden" which initially makes all of the div's hidden on page load.

All of the values for the checkboxes and input boxes are stored in a database, and I want to make it so if someone comes back to the form to update something, it correctly "shows" the divs that should be visible (the ones with values or specific checks).

Instead of writing a specific "if statement" for each field that I need to check, would it be possible to check all of the inputs within the divs that have the "start-hidden" class, and if the input is not empty, it will make that particular div visible?

Doing some research, I tried the following code, but I have a feeling i am completely off track.

```
    var inp = $(".start-hidden input").val();
    if(jQuery.trim(inp).length > 0){$(this).show();}
```

also, sometimes a "start-hidden" div might have another "start-hidden" div within it, I guess this would be a nested hidden div, but i need to make sure it only opens the parent div.

Hopefully this make sense to someone!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in the future it would help if you could post a snippet of your html too.

Comment: Another excellent way to get answers in the future is to accept answers that provide the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".start-hidden").each(function(){
    if( $.trim($(this).find(":text").val()).length > 0 || $(this).find(":checked").length > 0){
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: actually, how would we make it not mandatory that ALL input boxes within the hidden div are required to have something filled out. for example, one of the hidden divs has 3 questions in it, but it still needs to be visible if only 1 of the questions has text.

Comment: @steve: Can you post sample HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm over-thinking this because Cybermate's answer is so short and sweet but the way I understand the question I think there is more answer needed...

First you need to look at the **selector** you want to use for the INPUTS and not necessarily the DIVS.  I do this by using a common class in all inputs/checkboxes that I want to do something with.

```
$(".toggler").each(....);
```

Next you do need to have a way to link the INPUTS to the DIVS.  I usually do this with similar ID attributes.

```
<input id="name" type="text" class="formInput toggler" />
<div id="name1">Instructions for Name here</div>
```

Then you need to find a way to **bind an event** so that you can toggle the DIV when the event takes place.  In this case you've got both inputs and checkboxes.  These two are different and instead of checking .val() for the checkboxes you're probably going to want to test if the checkbox is checked or not.  When you determine that values are set or checkboxes are checked then you'll want to show the div.

```
$(".toggler").each(function() {
    var me = $(this);
    var myId = me.attr("id");
    var myDivId = "#"+myId+"1";

    if(me.is(":checkbox")) {
        //check the initial state of the checkbox
        if(me.is(":checked")) $(myDivId).show();

        // show/hide the div on clicking
        $("#"+myId).live('click', function() {
            $(myDivId).toggle();
        });
    } else {
        // check the initial state of the input
        if($.trim(me.val().length) > 0) {
            $(myDivId).toggle();
        }

        // if the state changes show the div
        $("#"+myId).live('change', function() {
            if($.trim($(this).val().length) > 0) {
                $(myDivId).show();
            } else {
                $(myDivId).hide();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net./kasdega/fzEG3/)